# How to decode JSON property that can be either array or single object with Swift JSONDecoder?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm trying to decode JSON object where one of the properties can be either array or single object. My idea was to introduce enum with `single` and `multiple` cases. Simplified code example below:

```swift
struct Show: Codable {
  var artistBio: ArtistBios?
}

enum ArtistBios: Codable {
  case single(ArtistBio)
  case multiple([ArtistBio])
  
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
    if container.count != nil {
      let value = try container.decode([ArtistBio].self)
      self = .multiple(value)
    } else {
      let value = try container.decode(ArtistBio.self)
      self = .single(value)
    }
  }
  
  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
    switch self {
      case .single(let artistBio):
        try container.encode(artistBio)
      case .multiple(let artistBios):
        try container.encode(artistBios)
    }
  }
}

struct ArtistBio: Codable {
  var name: String
  var url: String
}

let jsonStrArray = """
{
  "artistBio": [
    {
      "url": "url_to_pdf1",
      "name": "Artist Name 1"
    },
    {
      "url": "url_to_pdf2",
      "name": "Artist Name 2"
    }
  ]
}
"""

let jsonStrSingle = """
{
  "artistBio": {
    "url": "url_to_pdf1",
    "name": "Artist Name"
  }
}
"""


do {
  let show = try JSONDecoder().decode(Show.self, from: jsonStrArray.data(using: .utf8)!)
  print("show", show)
} catch (let error) {
  print("decode multiple error", error)
}

do {
  let show = try JSONDecoder().decode(Show.self, from: jsonStrSingle.data(using: .utf8)!)
  print("show", show)
} catch (let error) {
  print("decode single error", error)
}
```

I can't figure out the way how to properly decode my enum object. In both cases for single and array version of input JSON I get this error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, 
Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [
CodingKeys(stringValue: "artistBio", intValue: nil), 
_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], 
debugDescription: 
"Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", 
underlyingError: nil))
```

Comment: Use a `singleValueContainer` instead when you decode, and `try` to decode into `[ArtistBio].self` first, then if error - into `ArtistBio.self`

Comment: Yes it works, thanks. I was a bit mislead as documentation says you can decode single `primitive` value with `singleValueContainer`. I guess objects are primitive in this case :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `singleValueContainer`, not an `unkeyedContainer`, the latter expects always an array.

```
enum ArtistBios: Codable {
  case single(ArtistBio)
  case multiple([ArtistBio])
  
  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    do {
      let value = try container.decode([ArtistBio].self)
      self = .multiple(value)
    } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
      let value = try container.decode(ArtistBio.self)
      self = .single(value)
    }
  }
  
  func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    switch self {
      case .single(let artistBio):
        try container.encode(artistBio)
      case .multiple(let artistBios):
        try container.encode(artistBios)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest doing a more targeted `catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {..}` and let other errors (keyNotFound, dataCorrupted) actually propagate up on first try

Comment: @NewDev Good catch, thanks.